# number of different addends which sums to 41

Tags: summation, combinations

I have following equation:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{21} m_i = 41$$

where $m_i$ are non-negative integers.

How many different solutions are there. Note, that $41 + 0 + ... + 0$ is a different solution than $0 + 41 + 0 + ... + 0.

My only idea was to solve this recursive: let $P_a(s)$ the number of possible combinations, where a is the number of addends and s is the sum. (Im my case I want to calculate $P_{21}(41)$.

There is obviously this relation:

$$P_1(x) = 1\\P_a(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{a}P_{a-1}(i)$$

But there I stuck. Any ideas, how to approach this?

Comment: These are called [weak compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)), and the formula you seek is at that wiki link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's ${41+21-1} \choose {41}$.

The idea is [Stars ans bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)

You have 41 real objects and 20 dummy objects to represent borders. There's biection between all the orders of this 61 element and partitions of 41 to addends

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To represent each sum of $7$ non-negative integers that sum to $12$, we can use $6$ bars and $12$ dots:
$$
\bullet\bullet\bullet|\bullet\bullet|\bullet|\bullet\bullet\bullet\bullet|\bullet||\bullet
$$
represents $3+2+1+4+1+0+1$. The number of possible arrangements of the bars and dots is $\binom{18}{12}$.

Simiarly in your problem you would use $41$ dots and $20$ bars.

Comment: Great explanation!